# jQuery animate({top: x}) very laggy in everything but chrome

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to write a very simple animated sticky side bar using jQuery and its animate() function to change the top: CSS property of a div. Unfortunately in everything but chrome, it can get very laggy. I'm assuming its filling the memory every time the window scrolls and it calculates a newTop. Is there a better way to do this?

```
$(function() { // document ready 
    var $sticky = $('.sticky');
    var stickyTop = $sticky.offset().top;
    var padding = 0;
    var stickyMargin = parseInt($sticky.css('margin-top')) + padding;
    var intersection = stickyTop - stickyMargin;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (intersection < windowTop) {
            var newTop = (windowTop - intersection);
            $sticky.stop().animate({top: newTop}, 'slow');
        }
        else if ($sticky.offset().top != 0) {
            $sticky.stop().animate({top: 0}, 'slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: From what I can see from your code, the behaviour you're writing would annoy me such that I'd just adblock your sidebar. Why not make it just stick to the top of the window when it scrolls out of view instead of animating it all over the place? Please, do it for your users.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it works well in that context, I'm still interested in an answer to the question. It seems that if I call animate({top: 0}, 5000) on anything then the whole thing lags even if it is just a single call. Is it simply that anything other than chrome on the mac doesn't like the top property being animated on a relatively positioned element?

Comment: In fact, even just setting it to stick to the window when it scrolls out of view causes slow down (no animate() call)

Comment: http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/demos/stickybox/ looking for an effect like this. I'm very new to jQuery, so I can't see what makes this script so much more efficient other than being fixed positions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that I see is that every scroll action creates a animation which is queued in the render pipeline of your browser. You will need to debounce the animation, so you dont get an animation stack that makes the whole thing extremly buggy. For example you could wait a few milliseconds will the scroll is effectively registered. Have a look at [jQuery Timeout](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/). After that you can use it by editing the scroll() function in your script by

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $.doTimeout( 'scroll', 300, function(){
      // do your animation
   });
});
```